# Why is it in volitional form?

Tags: volitional-form

> 彼らは決して理解してくれないし、きみがなにを**しよう**とショックを受けるだろう。

What's the explanation of this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it in volitional form?
>
> > 彼らは決して理解してくれないし、きみがなにを**しよう**とショックを受けるだろう。

My native sense tells me that I don't find any volitional sense in this しよう unless it says しようとしようと, and in this, the first しよう is the one that conveys the volitional sense.

I find in this しよう alone, there is only the sense of ***do***.
It says きみが**なにをしようと** and this means ***whatever*** you ***do.***
This is the same as きみが何を**したとしても**ショックを受けるだろう.

It's [未然形（し）]+[助動詞（よう）] and the よう is used for the ***conditional*** sense.

> **5** （「ものならば」などを伴って）仮定の意を表す。「失敗なんかしようものなら許しませんよ」（[デジタル大辞泉 | よう [助動]](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226119/meaning/m1u/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86/)）